# Recover HP switch from failed firmware update

Tags: hp, switch, firmware

I have a HP V1910-16G (JE005A) switch which I decided to update the firmware on. I've downloaded the latest software package from the HP website (https://h10145.www1.hp.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=JE006A&lang=&cc=&prodSeriesId=&SoftwareReleaseUId=22014&SerialNumber=&PurchaseDate=) which gave me version 5.20 R1519P03. After rebooting the switch I could log in but after choosing two menu items I would be kicked out and have to log in again, no matter which menu items I clicked on, the same thing would happen. I then tried to reset to factory settings by powering off, connecting port 1 to port 2 with a patch lead and powering back on. Now I can no longer access the switch at all via the web console. I've also tried the console port but just get unintelligible characters on the screen.
Does anyone know how to rescue dead HP switches?

Comment: HPE will know, have you tried logging a call with them first?

Comment: No, we have no warranty or support cover for this switch.

Comment: HPE switches have lifetime warranty. :-)

Comment: Thanks Zach, I'll open a support case and see what they say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After raising a case with HPE support, they have agreed to replace both switches. Bonus! I did not know that HP switches came with a lifetime warranty.
Thanks to all who offered advice.

Comment: You should accept your own answer to keep this question from popping up as unanswered.